After Update to API level 34 app crashes on some Android devices
I updated my API level in accordance with newest Google Play Console requirements, but the app crashes on some Android devices.
I have the following in android/app/build.gradle
android {
    compileSdkVersion 34
...
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 33
        targetSdkVersion 34
...

In pubspec.yaml
  min_sdk_android: 33

It works on a lot of Android devices (e.g. Oppo A13 ColorOS, Samsung A71 A13, Samsung Galaxy Z A14),
but crashes on some (e.g. Pixel 8 A14).
From what I have seen it freezes on the start up launcher icon.
The latest release is the only active one in Google Play Console admin.
Why is it still crashing on some Android devices?

UPDATE:
Here is the stack trace:
Failed to find provider info for 24:95:2F:97:51:D9
NfcTag::connectionEventHandler: NDEF detection timed out
nativeNfcTag_doCheckNdefResult: unknown status=0xB2
Cannot get requestId: Handwriting was not initialized.
Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(Exception encountered, read, javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: error:1e000065:Cipher functions:OPENSSL_internal:BAD_DECRYPT
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.EVP_CipherFinal_ex(Native Method)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLEvpCipher.doFinalInternal(OpenSSLEvpCipher.java:152)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLCipher.engineDoFinal(OpenSSLCipher.java:374)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2074)
    at b0.h.b(Unknown Source:35)
    at a0.a.c(Unknown Source:11)
    at a0.a.k(Unknown Source:17)
    at a0.e$b.run(Unknown Source:233)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:959)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:232)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:317)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:85)
, null)
#0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:652)
#1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:310)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      main (package:myppcmetrics_app/main.dart:22)
<asynchronous suspension>
!!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 556)
Invalid frequency(-1), using 5G as default rssi array
View class com.android.systemui.keyguard.ui.view.UdfpsLottieViewWrapper is an AppCompat widget that can only be used with a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant).
View class com.android.systemui.keyguard.ui.view.UdfpsLottieViewWrapper is an AppCompat widget that can only be used with a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant).

I added error handling for the FlutterSecureStorage().read(key:'client_id') call as follows. Are there other errors that I don't see or handle at the moment?
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart';
import 'package:flutter_translate/flutter_translate.dart';
import 'package:myppcmetrics_app/config/theme.dart';
import 'package:myppcmetrics_app/screens/components/cockpit_charts.dart';
import 'package:myppcmetrics_app/screens/components/logo_header.dart';
import 'package:myppcmetrics_app/screens/components/menu.dart';
import 'package:myppcmetrics_app/service/translation.dart';
import 'package:myppcmetrics_app/state/client.dart';
import 'package:myppcmetrics_app/state/login.dart';
import 'package:myppcmetrics_app/state/route.dart' as custom_router;
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

final FlutterSecureStorage storage = const FlutterSecureStorage();

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  LocalizationDelegate delegate = await LocalizationDelegate.create(
      fallbackLocale: 'de',
      supportedLocales: ['de', 'it', 'fr', 'en'],
      preferences: TranslatePreferences());

  String? clientId;

  try {
    clientId = await storage.read(key: 'client_id');
  } catch (e) {
    await clearAllStorage();
  }

  String? chartOrderJson =
      await const FlutterSecureStorage().read(key: 'chart_order');
  List<ChartTypes> chartOrder = ChartTypes.values;
  if (chartOrderJson != null) {
    List<dynamic> chartOrderTmp = jsonDecode(chartOrderJson);
    chartOrder = [];
    for (int id in chartOrderTmp) {
      chartOrder.add(ChartTypes.fromId(id));
    }
  }
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
  ]);
  runApp(LocalizedApp(
      delegate,
      MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ListenableProvider<ClientState>(
            create: (context) => ClientState.create(
                clientId != null ? int.parse(clientId) : null),
          ),
          ListenableProvider<LoginState>(create: (context) {
            return LoginState(
                delegate.currentLocale.languageCode.toUpperCase(), chartOrder);
          }),
          ListenableProvider<custom_router.RouteState>(
              create: (context) => custom_router.RouteState.create(
                  custom_router.RouteState.login)),
        ],
        child: const MyPPCApp(),
      )));
}

Future<void> clearAllStorage() async {
  try {
    await storage.deleteAll();
    print('Secure storage cleared');
  } catch (e) {
    print('Error clearing secure storage: $e');
  }
}

After implementing these changes (clearAllStorage()), I app also crashes on Emulator with following error:
App com.google.android.youtube became active but still in NEVER bucket
updateValue is called with a value {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, which is lower than the previous value {24, 0, 86, 0, 24, 0, 44, 0}
updateValue is called with a value {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, which is lower than the previous value {6, 0, 24, 0, 185, 0, 24, 0}
updateValue is called with a value {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, which is lower than the previous value {521, 0, 684, 0, 1102, 0, 615, 0}
Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
App com.google.android.youtube became active but still in NEVER bucket
App com.google.android.youtube became active but still in NEVER bucket
No package ID 78 found for resource ID 0x780b000f.
No package ID 78 found for resource ID 0x780b000f.
PackageRecordCache: appContext was already set bbex@b1efbc5 -> bbex@4413849
Unable to match the desired swap behavior.
a: 3
File error accessing recents directory (directory doesn't exist?).
Unable to match the desired swap behavior.
device/generic/goldfish-opengl/system/GLESv2_enc/GL2Encoder.cpp:s_glGetUniformLocation:2206 GL error 0x502


minSdkVersion seems way too high, should 21 or something

a stack trace for the crash may help.

You can take a look at what's new for apps targeting API level 34/Android 14: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14

@MikkeIT Maybe I am not seeing the connection, but if minSdkVersion would be the reason and it is too high, wouldn't A14 work, but not A13?

@Chris Very new to flutter and app development. I guess, I have to build an emulator image to match the phone settings and run it to see the trace? I couldnt find a log that I could access on user's phone.

So how do you know it's causing crashes on some devices? Have you not got crashlytics or some other tool to help here?

I get reports from users of the apps in our company.

Come on, man. Get a stack trace. "It crashes" is amateur hour.

@spartygw I guess you missed the comment where I explained that I am not an app developer and I don't have access to the phones with the crashes. Can you explain where I get the stack trace from. An emulator?

Firebase Test Lab might be a way to try out the app on a model where it crashes. Crashlytics would be a way to automatically collect crash reports without physical access to the devices.

I added an update with the stack trace to my question.

I added error handling for the FlutterSecureStorage().read(key:'client_id') call as follows.
The following code used to load on the login page and couldn't handle FlutterSecureStorage().read(key: 'client_id') when the user had old app data from previous versions stored.
String? clientId = await const FlutterSecureStorage().read(key: 'client_id');

If the clientId isn't available because the user isn't logged in, I run now first clearAllStorage().
String? clientId;

try {
  clientId = await storage.read(key: 'client_id');
} catch (e) {
  await clearAllStorage();
}

It seems to work now.
This wasn't an issue when the app was launched, because the app was new and nobody had old app data on their devices. We haven't made any updates until now when it became an issue.
